# How to append JSON data into select tag in ajax javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC5 project and I am calling a webservice in my project with ajax. Every thing is ok so far and at the end the city names can be appended into the `select` tag, but the code below doesn't work:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function f1() {
            var token="";
            $.ajax({
                data: { webservice_username: 'webservice_usernam', password: 'password' },
                url: 'http://www.travelinsure.ir/api/v1.1/authenticate',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (idx, result) {
                        token = result;
                        f2(result);
                    })
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x.responseText);
                    alert(z);
                }
            });
        }
        function f2(token) {
            // alert('New: '+token);
            $.ajax({
                data: { token: token },
                url: 'http://www.travelinsure.ir/api/v1.1/getcitylist?token=',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    results = JSON.stringify(data);
                    // a = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(results);
                    a = $.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(a);
                    $.each(data, function (idx, r) {
                        $("#sel").append("<option value='" + r.city_id + "'>'" + r.city_name + "'</option>");
                        alert(result.city_name);
                    })
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x.responseText);
                    alert(z);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Click!!!" onclick="f1()" />
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <select id="sel">
            <option>لیست شهرهای ایران</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are appending the option in the wrong way.

Do it like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {   
     $('#sel').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",item.city_id).text(item.city_name)); 
});
```

You could also add a new option like this:

```
$.each(data, function (key, item) {
    $("#sel").get(0).options[$("#sel").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.city_name, item.city_id);
});
```